# How to switch between two different remote origin in git

Tags: git, github, azure-devops

Suppose you have two remotes set for your project. For example: One remote named `ABC` points to Microsoft Azure Devops and other remote named `XYZ` points to github. How do you switch the remote branch to which local master branch is currently pointing at?

Answer (score 1):

The way I do this trick is by using `--set-upstream-to`

```
git checkout local-branch
git branch --set-upstream-to=one-remote/remote-branch
```

It the branches have the same name in local and remote:

```
git checkout local-branch
git branch --set-upstream-to=one-remote
```